# BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, options) cause null point exception

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

I am trying to load the selected image from gallery into a imageView. I managed to do that with small picture. When I choose the bigger picture, then the app will close and it will show java.out.of.memory. After googling, I found that I can add an option to decodeFile but it cause the null point exception. Here is my coding.

```
if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst(); //TODO google

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();

    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Bitmap temp = null;
    temp=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, options);
    float ratio = temp.getWidth()/temp.getHeight();
    int width = 480;
    int height = Math.round(width/ratio);
    pic = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(temp, width, height, false);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(pic);
}
```

Without options in temp=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, options);, I cant open big size picture, with options in temp=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, options);, I got null point exception.

Comment: Can you post your logcat output?

Comment: in your code path you should check cursor != null and check picturePath exists before do anything  (I don't know English)

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I have identified my problem and solve it by referring to this website http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html